# Cocos2d-x CCLabelTTF enableStroke is time consuming

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, lag, outline, cclabelttf

We're developing iOS application and encountered a problem with labels' outlines.

It seems, that creating outlines(for 20-30 labels) takes more time now, than anything else. The  creating lag is about 2-3 seconds, what is too long.

Can anyone say what solution we could use, or why it is so?

Instruments' screen:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the label's text needs to change at runtime, consider using bitmap fonts with pre-rendered outlines. Or create all labels up-front and re-use them if their text doesn't change.

You'll find an explanation as to why changing text as well as shadow/outline properties are slow in the [CCLabelTTF class reference](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCLabelTTF.html) (for Cocos2D-Swift but the same applies to cocos2d-x) and the [Labels section in the dev guide](https://www.makeschool.com/docs/?source=mgwu#!/cocos2d/1.3/concepts/cocos2d-nodes) (same here).

Specifically consider that changing font size or padding enlarges the label's texture and that alone can increase the time it takes to render shadow/outline. So does changing the size of the shadow/outline itself. It needn't necessarily be because the font rendering in cocos2d-x might have changed.